# cleaning content with php

Tags: php, html, forms, hyperlink

I am currently using a textfile, and writing its content in to a list. On the list, I simply use GET parameters to receive the value of the chosen link in the list. When I click on the chosen link, I want to write the value of the link. The situation is that the list is still there and the value is written under it. How can I solve this? I need the list to disappear, and only show the name of the chosen link. I use if statements, but it doesnt work.

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Inlämning3</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js" >
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="valideraFilmer.js" >
</script>


</head>

<body>

<?php
// Skriva film och info till en textfil
if( isset ($_POST['name'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $grade = $_POST['options'];
    $link = $_POST['link'];
    $pic = $_POST['pic'];
    $story = $_POST['story'];

    $myFile = "filmer.txt";
    $handle = fopen($myFile, 'a');

    if(!empty($name)){
        fwrite($handle, $name. ";");
        fwrite($handle, $grade. ";");
        fwrite($handle, $link. ";");
        fwrite($handle, $pic. ";");
        fwrite($handle, $story. "\n");
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
?>

<div id="page">
    <?php
        include("header.php");
    ?>
    <div id="leftbar">
        <form id="form" method="post" action="Filmer-PHP.php" >
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Lägg till en film:</legend>
                Titel:
                <br><input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
                Betyg:
                <br><select id="options" name="options">
                    <option value="0">Välj betyg här...</option>
                    <option value="*"> *</option>
                    <option value="**"> **</option>
                    <option value="***"> ***</option>
                    <option value="****"> ****</option>
                    <option value="*****"> *****</option>                       
                </select>
                <br>
                Länk till imdb:
                <br><input type="text" name="link" id="link"><br>
                Länk till bild:
                <br><input type="text" name="pic" id="pic"><br>
                Filmens handling:
                <br><textArea cols="20" rows="3" name="story" id="story"></textarea><br>
                <br><input type="submit" name="button" value="Spara film" id="button">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="rightbar">
        <h2>Filmer</h2>

        <?php
        // Läsa av och visa titel och betyg

            if(!isset($readin)){
                $readin = file('filmer.txt');
                $ul = '<ul id="films">';
                echo $ul;
                foreach($readin as $fName){
                    $lineSplit = explode(";", $fName);
                    if(isset($lineSplit[1])){
                        echo '<li>'.'<a href="Filmer-PHP.php?name=' .$lineSplit[0]. '">'.$lineSplit[0].'<span>'.$lineSplit[1].'</span>'.'</a>'.'</li>';
                    }
                }
            }
        ?>

        <?php
        // Läsa av och visa detaljerad info om filmer
            if(isset($_GET['name'])){
                $name = $_GET['name'];
                $readin = file('filmer.txt');
                foreach($readin as $fName){
                    $lineSplit = explode(";", $fName);
                    $lineSplit[0] = $name;
                }
                echo $lineSplit[0];
            }
        ?>

    </div>
        <?php
            include("footer.php");
        ?>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code is fairly clean but could you make your question a little bit more relative to a certain part of the code that you're trying to make work out for you? "when i click on it, i want to write the name" What do you mean? You want to write it in a text box, you want to copy the name from the option?

Comment: Can you be more specific. I don't understand what you mean with "writing under lists" and such...

Comment: By the way, don't comment your code in Swedish, always document your code in an international language, like English, that will allow anyone who take over your system (never assume that it can't happen, in this example you need help and the Swedish part won't do much for over 99% of the users here).

Comment: im sorry for the bad english. what i meant is that currently, im printing a list in a div. I want to replace this list with the value of the chosen link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before starting to create the list at:

```
 if(!isset($readin)){
```

add following line before the above:

```
 if(!isset($_GET['name'])) {
```

and after that list building add

```
 } else {
   echo $_GET['name'];
 }
```

that will make the list not show when the parameter name was not passed. It will also print the name instead of the list.
I read your question like 3 times before I understood your english.
Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked fine. Im sorry for the bad english, i will try to explain better next time.